# MIMIC III - Inputevents_mv\ inputevents_cv IV pumps

Tags: mimic-iii

were the pumps in use when the data for inputevents_mv \inputevents_cv tables was collected, smart pumps? I'm asking because I wonder if the starttime\endtime was entered manually or not for the IV inputs.